# Setting name of attachment URL

Tags: images, urls, attachments

I have a problem I need to fix with the URLs that are generated for the attachment pages of images with metadata.

I’m working on a photography site where individual photos are displayed as attachments to a post, via `attachment.php`.

The URL scheme for displaying these photos is something like this:

`domain.com/project-name/attachment/attachment-name`.

If I upload an image without any metadata, then the last part of the attachment URL is taken from the file name of the image. So, if the image is `ABCD.jpg`, then the URL is `domain.com/project-name/attachment/ABCD`. All good.

However, if the image *does* have a title in the metadata, then the URL is set to that title: `domain.com/project-name/attachment/omg-cool-photo`.

Is it possible to have a metadata title with a photo, but to also have the URL that is set for the attachment to remain as the photo filename? If so, how?

I took a look around but I couldn’t see anything about this here already. Sorry if it is and I missed it.

Any help gratefully received!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can hook onto `add_attachment` and force the slug to work off the filename like so:

**Update:** To uppercase the slug, you'll need to add a temporary filter onto `wp_unique_post_slug`. You can't simply use `strtoupper( $slug )` as WordPress sanitises (lowercases) it within the update function.

```
/**
 * Force attachment slug to ignore title from metadata (if any).
 * 
 * @link http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/140132/1685
 * 
 * @param int $post_id
 */
function wpse_140132_attachment_slug_as_file_name( $post_id ) {
    if ( $post = get_post( $post_id ) ) {
        if ( $file = get_attached_file( $post->ID ) ) {
            // Get file name, without extension.
            $slug = pathinfo( $file, PATHINFO_FILENAME );

            // Only update if different to current slug!
            if ( $slug && $slug != $post->post_name ) {
                add_filter( 'wp_unique_post_slug', 'wpse_140132_attachment_slug_as_file_name_uppercase', 50 );
                wp_update_post(
                    array(
                        'ID' => $post->ID,
                        'post_name' => $slug,
                    )
                );
                remove_filter( 'wp_unique_post_slug', 'wpse_140132_attachment_slug_as_file_name_uppercase', 50 );
            }
        }
    }
}

add_action( 'add_attachment', 'wpse_140132_attachment_slug_as_file_name' );

/**
 * @see     wpse_140132_attachment_slug_as_file_name()
 * 
 * @param   string  $slug
 * @return  string
 */
function wpse_140132_attachment_slug_as_file_name_uppercase( $slug ) {
    return strtoupper( $slug );
}
```

Comment: Thank you, kind internet sir!

Is there any way to also easily get the letters in the filename to be in uppercase in the URL? Yes, I know it sounds crazy...

Comment: That's a little trickier, but not impossible. See revised answer.